# Is there any way to remove activity history in Trello?

Tags: trello

Is there a way to get rid of activity history in Trello's cards in the same way you can delete comments for a card?

Answer (score 3):

Deleting non-comment actions is not currently possible. However, making the board private will make those actions visible only to board members.

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete the activity history of a specific card.  However, you can effectively do this by copying the card and deleting the original card.  The new card will have the same name and details as the old card (make sure to copy across any checklists and members).  The new card's activity history will only show one action:

**User** copied this card from *Card Name* in list *List Name*

Answer (score 2):

If you use Stylish or Stylebot to customize how web pages appear in your browser, you can add this small rule to show only comments from the Trello feed

```
.phenom:not(.phenom-comment) {
   display: none;
}
```

It doesn't delete the activity, it just hides it on the cards.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome or Firefox Browser, you can hide the activity history in your Trello cards using [Hide activity entries](http://beingmrkenny.co.uk/trello-user-scripts/hide.html) extension.